# ASP.NET Core API HTTP POST request Swagger Example does not have collection field as declared

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, entity-framework-core, swagger

I'm creating a API of HTTP Post request that take param is a BillDTO, which has BillDetails, a List of BillDetail, as its field.

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult AddBill(BillDTO newBill)
        {
            var createdBill = _billService.AddBill(newBill);
            return Created(createdBill.Id.ToString(), createdBill);
        }

public class BillDTO
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public double Total { get; set; }

        public List<BillDetail> BillDetails = new List<BillDetail>();
    }
```

But the Swagger example value doesn't have this List field, I tried to type as below but it didn't take effect:

```
//Example value:
{
  "date": "2022-08-23T08:11:22.281Z",
  "total": 0
}

//What I tried to execute
{
  "date": "2022-08-23T08:11:22.281Z",
  "total": 0,
  "billDetails": 
    {
        {
            "menuItem":
                {
                    "id": 1
                }
        }
        {
            "menuItem":
                {
                    "id": 2
                }
        }    
    } 
}
```

**Only "date" and "total" are read by the application.** What **should I do to my code** for the app to recognize billDetails in Swagger example?

Comment: Can you share your `BillDetail` class?

Comment: I FIXED IT, thanks for your concern, there is no problem with the BillDetail class. The property BillDetails of BillDTO didn't have the {get; set;} which caused the problem.